# Eudora email migration

Tags: email, migration

When Lion comes out, PPC Rosetta support for the Eudora email app is reported not to be available.

Which contemporary Mac OS X email clients might support the most painless and reliable importing and use of 10 years worth of of Eudora messages, contacts, filters, and settings?  Which current and supported email clients have the largest subset of Eudora's capabilities?

What problems might I encounter during a complete Eudora export, and how might I avoid them?

Answer (score 1):

I've used [Eudora Mailbox Cleaner](http://homepage.mac.com/aamann/Eudora_Mailbox_Cleaner.html) to varied success for a few recent-ish switchers, with the added bonus (for me, at least) that it can import messages from Thunderbird. It is, however, a PowerPC app in itself, so you'd need to run it before upgrading to Mac OS X 10.7 Lion.

Answer (score 0):

I left behind eudora some time back, but loved the four part article on [migrating 16 years of email from eudora to gmail](http://tidbits.com/article/12036) by Adam Engst.

Even if you don't want it there permanently, you can still use Eudora and test things. Gmail uses IMAP so everything will sync well to Apple Mail or Outlook (which is really quite good in it's 2011 version). Mailplane is nice, too.

As for clients - the Lion apple mail looks great - so you can get things tidy and then evaluate that once it ships.

Best of luck!

Also - TidBits has some wonderful Take Control books and has [two about preparing for and using Lion](http://www.tidbits.com/article/12288). The first on preparing is out, and the other is waiting for the general release of Lion / Devloper NDA to be lifted before shipping.

Comment: Why would anyone need 16 years of email?

Comment: I know! Back when it was only text, 10 years of mail in elm was perfectly reasonable for me personally. I'll have to give Adam a huge benefit of the doubt for migrating that amount of information forward. It's clearly central to his career.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Tidbits article on [Switching from Eudora to Apple Mail](http://tidbits.com/article/9564) from 13-Apr-2008.